How to Map Zip Code Prefixes to States in R Without External Files and not using zipcodeR
I'm working on a spatial analysis project in R where I need to map the first three digits of zip codes (zip code prefixes) to their corresponding U.S. states. Due to constraints, I cannot use external files or packages that require data downloads. because of cloud servise I have to use, zipcodeR package doesn't load. 
Not trying to fix this, looking for an alternative to zipcodeR to do this, eventually I can do some spatial analysis of count data.
zipcode=c("014**", "018**", "119**", "165**", "165**", "240**")

get_state_from_zip_prefix <- function(zip_code) {
  # Extract the first three digits
  zip_prefix <- substr(zip_code, 1, 3)
  # Use reverse_zipcode to get state information
  zip_info <- reverse_zipcode(paste0(zip_prefix, "00"))
  # Return the state if available
  if (!is.null(zip_info)) {
    return(zip_info$state)
  } else {
    return(NA)
  }
}

it returns as NA

Maybe this is a data source you could download outside of R and then reference: https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/zip-code-database/

The first 3 digits of a zip code are not guaranteed to map to a single state. For example, there are zip codes starting with 205 in Virginia, Maryland and DC. This is uncommon but does happen.
If you have the full zip codes, a simple lookup function should do the trick. We can use public zip code data such as the free csv file found via in this link to construct a minimal lookup table based on all the contiguous blocks of zip codes mapping to states.
lookup <- data.frame(
  State = c("NY", "PR", "VI", "PR", "MA", "RI", "NH", "ME", "VT", "MA", "VT", 
            "CT", "NY", "CT", "NJ", "AE", "NY", "PA", "DE", "DC", "VA", "DC",
            "MD", "DC", "VA", "DC", "MD", "VA", "WV", "NC", "SC", "GA", "FL", 
            "AA", "FL", "AL", "TN", "MS", "GA", "KY", "OH", "IN", "MI", "IA", 
            "WI", "MN", "DC", "SD", "ND", "MT", "IL", "MO", "KS", "NE", "LA", 
            "AR", "MO", "AR", "OK", "TX", "OK", "TX", "OK", "TX", "CO", "WY", 
            "ID", "WY", "ID", "UT", "AZ", "NM", "TX", "DC", "NV", "CA", "AP", 
            "HI", "AS", "HI", "GU", "PW", "FM", "MP", "MH", "OR", "WA", "AK"),
  min = c(501L, 601L, 801L, 901L, 1001L, 2801L, 3031L, 3901L, 5001L, 5501L, 
          5601L, 6001L, 6390L, 6401L, 7001L, 9001L, 10001L, 15001L, 19701L, 
          20001L, 20101L, 20201L, 20588L, 20590L, 20598L, 20599L, 20601L, 
          22003L, 24701L, 27006L, 29001L, 30002L, 32003L, 34001L, 34101L, 
          35004L, 37010L, 38601L, 39813L, 40003L, 43001L, 46001L, 48001L, 
          50001L, 53001L, 55001L, 56901L, 57001L, 58001L, 59001L, 60001L, 
          63001L, 66002L, 68001L, 70001L, 71601L, 72643L, 72644L, 73001L,
          73301L, 73401L, 73960L, 74001L, 75001L, 80001L, 82001L, 83201L, 
          83414L, 83415L, 84001L, 85001L, 87001L, 88510L, 88888L, 88901L, 
          90001L, 96201L, 96701L, 96799L, 96801L, 96910L, 96939L, 96941L, 
          96950L, 96960L, 97001L, 98001L, 99501L), 
  max = c(544L, 795L, 851L, 988L, 2791L, 2940L, 3897L, 4992L, 5495L, 5544L, 
          5907L, 6389L, 6390L, 6928L, 8989L, 9978L, 14925L, 19640L, 19980L, 
          20098L, 20199L, 20586L, 20588L, 20597L, 20598L, 20599L, 21930L, 
          24658L, 26886L, 28909L, 29945L, 31999L, 33994L, 34099L, 34997L, 
          36925L, 38589L, 39776L, 39901L, 42788L, 45999L, 47997L, 49971L, 
          52809L, 54990L, 56763L, 56999L, 57799L, 58856L, 59937L, 62999L, 
          65899L, 67954L, 69367L, 71497L, 72642L, 72643L, 72959L, 73199L, 
          73344L, 73951L, 73960L, 74966L, 79999L, 81658L, 83128L, 83406L, 
          83414L, 83877L, 84791L, 86556L, 88439L, 88595L, 88888L, 89883L, 
          96162L, 96698L, 96797L, 96799L, 96898L, 96932L, 96940L, 96944L, 
          96952L, 96970L, 97920L, 99403L, 99950L))

Now we use a little wrapper function to allow easy lookup of multiple zip codes at once:
state_from_zip <- function(zips, lookup) {
    
  unlist(lapply(zips, function(zip) {
    zip <- as.numeric(zip)
    val <- which(lookup$min <= zip & lookup$max >= zip)
    if(length(val) == 0) NA else lookup$State[val[1]]
  }))
}

Testing some famous zip codes, we get:
zips <- c(WhiteHouse = "20500", EmpireState = "10118", BeverleyHills = "90210")

state_from_zip(zips, lookup)
#>   WhiteHouse   EmpireState BeverleyHills 
#>         "DC"          "NY"          "CA" 

If you only have the first 3 numbers of the zip code, then the above code should still work if you append a "00" to them (i.e. state_from_zip(paste0(prefixes, "00"), lookup)), though you might get some inaccuracies around Washington (and possibly elsewhere) for the reasons outlined above.
